# Does boundness in Topological vector space depend on the base point we choose?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let X be a topological vector space,we know bounded set $B$ defined as for any neiborhood of origin,there exist some $\lambda$ such that $B\subset \lambda U$.

Does this depend on the base point we choose (for example here we choose definition for the neiborhood at origin.) Can we show this definition is equivalent to given point $x\ne 0 $ any neiborhood $U_x$ exist $\lambda$ such that $V\subset \lambda U$?

No since bounded set under translation(which is continuous linear map) is also bounded

Comment: If you want to shift the point you take neighborhoods of, you should also shift the scaling and ask for $B\subset \lambda(U-x)+x$, where $\lambda(U-x)+x = \{ \lambda(u-x)+x \,|\, x\in U\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose $x=(1,0)$ in $\mathbb R^2$, then the unit ball $B=B_1(0,0)$ will not be bounded according to your definition.  This is because if $U=B_{1/2}(x)$, then one would never have
$$
B\subseteq\lambda U,
$$
because $(0,0)$ is not in $\lambda U$, unless $\lambda=0$, which clearly doesn't work either.

As an alternative, instead of $\lambda U$, one may consider  homothety relative to $x$, meaning the map
$$
  h_\lambda(u) = \lambda(u-x) + x = \lambda u + (1-\lambda)x.
$$

This is like multiplying by $\lambda$ when the origin is changed to $x$.  It is now easy to see that a set $B$ is bounded if and only if, for any neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists some $\lambda$ such that $B\subseteq h_\lambda(U)$.

Comment: Thanks,do you mean since the scalaring (at origin) will change the base point?Hence we first shift the ball to origin,scalar it by $\lambda$ then go back to point $x$?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it!